# An unexpected DCOM error occurred while trying to automatically attach to the remote web server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've two web sites running on my IIS 7.5. Both on port 80. Since they are both on the same port, I have to stop one to start the other. I am not using the inbuilt cassini server. Debugging works fine when using cassini.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to debug my mvc application (which was created under the second website) I get the error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. An unexpected DCOM error
>   occurred while trying to automatically attach to the remote web
>   server. Try manually attaching to the remote web server using the
>   'Attach To Process' dialog.

The web application has windows authentication enabled.  Any ideas?

**Additional details** : I'm able to do a "attach to process" and debug it. But cannot debug using <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Connect as property of the website to Application user.

Comment: Sorry, how do you do this?  And where?

Answer (score 6):

Although I was trying to remotely debug a simple *.exe application running on a different machine but I was getting very similar error mentioned by the OP.

> Unable to attach to the process. A DCOM error occurred trying to
>   contact the remote computer. Access is denied.
>
> It may be possible to avoid this error by changing your settings to
>   debug only native code or only managed code.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/a-dcom-error-occurred-trying-to-contact-the-remote-computer-access-is-denied) Microsoft documentation and following below step helped resolve my error:

- Turn off Native Compatibility Mode and Managed Compatibility Mode.

You can follow below screen shot to achieve the same:

[image]

I didn't require to reboot the machine. You can also try that way and if it doesn't work then go ahead the reboot the machine.

Comment: Yeah, but one problem with this is that - when you're debugging - the Debugger (like in the Locals or Watch window) can't use  anything related to Reflection - like Type, PropertyInfo, etc.